# How to properly split up a large sql table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to design a database which has to deal with 5 different types of orders, I was going to have one large order table which had the fields for every type or order but it was too large.

The way I had in mind was as below, where each order has a unique id, the id of the person who placed the order and the id of the order_type table which is where the order specifics will be stored.

**order**
id
user_id (foreign key to USER.id)
order_date
order_type2_id (foreign key to ORDER_TYPE1.id)
order_type3_id (foreign key to ORDER_TYPE2.id)
order_type4_id (foreign key to ORDER_TYPE3.id)
order_type5__id (foreign key to ORDER_TYPE4.id)
order_type6_id (foreign key to ORDER_TYPE5.id)

**order_type1**
id

**order_type2**
id

**order_type3**
id

**order_type4**
id

**order_type5**
id

Would it be better to store all the data in just one large table and null the fields that are not used or am I on the right track by having separate tables and joining them somehow. A point in the right direction would be great as I feel my solution is incorrect.

Comment: Any time you're writing "table1", "table2", or "column1", "column2" you're probably on the wrong track. If each order is nothing more than an ID, it sounds like a job for an enum field for the order type. What differentiates these orders? What other fields will you be associating with each order? What fields will only apply to certain types of orders?

Comment: Those names are just for the question, each table has roughly 20-50 columns that are unique to the order. There are 5 different types of orders, if I had to have one table called order and have the columns for every single type of order in there it would be close to 200 columns in one table. I had a huge table with a column called order type and stored it all but I thought it may be better to separate each order type  into a sub-table to make it easier to work with.

Comment: Supplying some idea of what information is unique to each order type, and what is in common, will help us answer the question. Also what each order type represents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be simpler transaction-wise to just have one table, which generally translates to just one object in the business layer. You don't need joins if for some reason you need to pull all orders in at some point. Null fields don't take up much if any space if they are variable, fixed fields however take up same space as their width.

Answer (score 0):

This is a question of Database design and normalization.

You need to answer basic database design questions like:

- What is the purpose of the different order types in your database?
- What data is contained by the different order types?
- Are there structural differences in the data for each of the order types?
- How is the data from the order types used?
- Are Order Types a required field for each order?
- etc

Off hand, I would suggest you are chasing an overly complex concept of what is needed in your end database.

Consider this...
If the data structure for the 5 order types is the same, you really only need one order type field.

`order_table
id (primary key BIGINT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,)
user_id (foreign key to USER.id BIGINT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL)
order_date (DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',)
order_type_id (foreign key to order.type TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL)`

handle the joins via application code

- if order type is 0 join on order table 0 with lookup order ID
- if order type is 1 join on order table 1 with lookup order ID
- if order type is 2 join on order table 2 with lookup order ID
- if order type is 3 join on order table 3 with lookup order ID
- if order type is 4 join on order table 4 with lookup order ID

but the key here is you have not supplied enough information to correctly assess database design and how to apply normalization to your tables to handle the issue that your current Order table exceeds your host's mysql limitations (maybe consider a different host or a VPS hosting option).

additional reading https://www.codeproject.com/articles/359654/important-database-designing-rules-which-i-fo

Comment: There are 5 orders types with up to 50 columns that is unique to each order, I had a large table that stored it all with an order_type and id column. I thought by creating a sub-table for each order type it would make it easier to work with.

Comment: 50 columns that are unique to each order or 50 columns that are unique to each order_type? Those are two very different things in database design.